# How to fill background color of row in node js xlsx npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, xlsx

I need to read a excel sheet and after checking data from backend need to color row . I am able to read and create new sheet with new data but fill is not working here for a cell/row .

This is my code , I am using xlsx npm

```
  let cell = workingSheet['C'+i];
  console.log(cell)
  workingSheet['A'+i].v = "PROCESSED"+i;
  workingSheet['A'+i].s = { fill: { fgColor: { rgb: "#111111" } } };
  console.log(
    workingSheet['A'+i]
  )
  xlsx.writeFile(spreadsheet, `./sheets/output/mysheet.xls`);
```

Answer (score 4):

This example shows how to color the cell background. The problems was that, there were no pattern type: **"solid"**, and the color code does not needs the beginning **#**.
This does not works with **xlsx** package, but **xlsx-color**.

```
"use strict";
var xlsx = require("xlsx-color");
var spreadsheet = xlsx.utils.book_new();
var xf = "./sheets/output/mysheet.xls";

var sheets = {
  "Munkafüzet1": [
    ["M1A1", "M1B1", "M1C1", "M1D1"],
    ["M1A2", "M1B2", "M1C2", "M1D2"],
    ["M1A2", "M1B2", "M1C2", "M1D2"],
    ["M1A2", "M1B2", "M1C2", "M1D2"],
    ["M1A2", "M1B2", "M1C2", "M1D2"],
  ]
};

for (var sheet of Object.keys(sheets)) {
  xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(
    spreadsheet,
    xlsx.utils.aoa_to_sheet(sheets[sheet]),
    sheet
  );
}

var i;
for (i = 1; i <= sheets["Munkafüzet1"].length; i++) {
spreadsheet.Sheets["Munkafüzet1"]["A"+i].s = {
  fill: {
    patternType: "solid",
    fgColor: { rgb: "111111" }
  }
  };
}

xlsx.writeFile(spreadsheet, xf);
```

Answer (score 2):

According to this [thread](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/906).

> We offer this in the [Pro compendium](https://sheetjs.com/pro). Since companies have paid for the
> features already, it would be unfair to them if we turned around and
> made it available as open source. [We have a longer comment in a gist.](https://gist.github.com/SheetJSDev/24b8acd317d01999d721b38de7c53021)

Comment: I started to use the xlsx, but when I had to realize, a simple text color setting or allign is declared as a "pro" feature, which is sad and funny in one, I had to start use another stuff for excel creation. The new player is became the excelJs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs), which contains a lot of mandatory and bacis features without a "pro" limitation.

I found this tool in this guide: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/how-to-export-to-excel-in-angular/